# csvファイルを任意の列で２つの配列に分割する方法について

Tags: c#, csv

初心者のため、C#に詳しくなくご相談します。

いま、CSVファイルがあり、3列目までが説明変数、
4列目が目的変数として、4組のデーターを解析したいと思っています。

・「inputfile.csv」

```
　0.00625, 0.03448276, 0.0483871, 0.04
　0.21875, 0.2068966,  0.2580645, 0.24
　0.46875, 0.4137931,  0.5483871, 0.52
　1,　　   1,         1,         1
```

これを、コンボボックス1に次の通り埋め込んでコンパイルすると計算が成功します。

```
comboValue == "1"


  trainData.Add(new NData(new List<double>() { 0.00625, 0.03448276, 0.0483871 }, new List<double>() { 0.04 }));
  trainData.Add(new NData(new List<double>() { 0.21875, 0.2068966, 0.2580645 }, new List<double>() { 0.24 }));
  trainData.Add(new NData(new List<double>() { 0.46875, 0.4137931, 0.5483871 }, new List<double>() { 0.52 }));
  trainData.Add(new NData(new List<double>() { 1, 1, 1 }, new List<double>() { 1 }));
```

上述の方法では、データー毎に埋め込んでコンパイルしないといけません。
汎用的にCSVファイルを読み込んで、説明変数をX、目的変数をYとしてCSV形式で読み込んで、
実施するコンボボックス「FILE」を作成しました。

説明変数X、目的変数Yは正しく読み込まれていることを確認出来ましたが、最後にXData、YDataに格納する際に、comboValue == "1"のように、Xが３配列、Yが１配列になりません。
さらに、i,jが読み取れないとエラーになります。

```
  trainData.Add(new NData(new List<double>() { XData[i, j] }, new List<double>() { YData[i, j7] }));
```

単純なCSVファイルを読み込んで、格納するだけの処理ですが、初心者のため失敗続きでした。
ご助言頂けますと有難く存じます。

記

```
namespace NNet{
    public partial class Form1 : Form{              

        private NTrainer trainer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new string[]{ "1", "2", "3", "File" });
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 3;

        }

        private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
         


                List<NData> trainData = new List<NData>();

            if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

            if(trainer == null) {
                var comboValue = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                if (comboValue == "1")
                {
                    trainData.Add(new NData(new List<double>() { 0.00625, 0.03448276, 0.0483871 }, new List<double>() { 0.04 }));
                    trainData.Add(new NData(new List<double>() { 0.21875, 0.2068966, 0.2580645 }, new List<double>() { 0.24 }));
                    trainData.Add(new NData(new List<double>() { 0.46875, 0.4137931, 0.5483871 }, new List<double>() { 0.52 }));
                    trainData.Add(new NData(new List<double>() { 1, 1, 1 }, new List<double>() { 1 }));
                }
                else if (comboValue == "2")


                  ･･････（途中省略）･･････


                else if (comboValue == "File")
                {

                    List<double> numbers = new List<double>();
                    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("inputfile.csv"))
                    {
                        foreach (string word in line.Split(',')){
                            numbers.Add(Double.Parse(word));


                            //確認用　
                   
                            string[] cols = word.Split(',');
                            for (int n = 0; n < cols.Length; n++)

                                MessageBox.Show(cols[n]);

                            //確認用終了

                        }
                    }

                    //確認用

                    using (StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter("output.csv", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS")))

                        foreach (var s in numbers)
                        {
                            sWriter.WriteLine("{0} ", s);  
                        }

                    //確認用終了


                    int NDP = 4;
                    int Input_Unit = 3;
                    int Output_Unit = 1;

                    double[,] XData = new double[NDP, Input_Unit];
                    double[,] YData = new double[NDP, Output_Unit];

                    int line_count = 4; 
                    int col_count = 4; 

                    // 2次元配列の定義
                    double[,] InData = new double[line_count, col_count];
                    int a = 0, b = 0;
                    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("inputfile.csv"))
                    {
                        foreach (string word in line.Split(','))
                        {                         
                            InData[a, b] = Convert.ToDouble(word);
                            b++;
                        }


                        //確認用

                        using (StreamWriter sWriter2 = new StreamWriter("output2.csv", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS")))

                            foreach (var t in InData)
                            {
                                sWriter2.WriteLine("{0} ", t);  
                            }

                        //確認用終了


                        for (int i = 0; i < NDP; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < Input_Unit; j++)
                            {
                                XData[i, j] = InData[i, j];                                
                            }

                            using (StreamWriter sWriter3 = new StreamWriter("outputX.csv", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS")))

                                foreach (var t in XData)
                                {
                                    sWriter3.WriteLine("{0} ", t); 
                                }

                            int jb = Input_Unit;

                            for (int j7 = 0; j7 < Output_Unit; j7++)
                            {
                                YData[i, j7] = InData[i, jb + j7];

                                using (StreamWriter sWriter4 = new StreamWriter("outputY.csv", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS")))

                                    foreach (var t in YData)
                                    {
                                        sWriter4.WriteLine("{0} ", t);  
                                    }

                                trainData.Add(new NData(new List<double>() { XData[i, j] }, new List<double>() { YData[i, j7] }));

                             }

                        }

                        b = 0;
                        a++;
                    }


                }
            } else {
                trainData = trainer.NData;
            }

            if(trainData.Count > 0){
                Run(trainData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `さらに、i,jが読み取れないとエラーになります。`で示された該当行の`XData[i, j]`の部分で、`j`の変数がスコープ外のようです。それから`NTrainer`とか`NData`が未定義なので問題の再現が難しいですね。その辺を追加して、また途中省略の部分も処理は無くても何かしら有効なソースコードにして、ビルドが通るようにしてみてください。

Comment: ご知見有難うございました。 何とか解決出来ました。
有難うございました。

Comment: マルチポスト先⇒ http://bbs.wankuma.com/index.cgi?mode=al2&namber=98841

Answer (score 0):

csvという決まったルールのファイルを扱う時にパッケージを使った方がいいではないかと思います。

例えばこのパッケージ：

https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/